# Creating Custom Charuco boards

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, aruco

I am working on some calibration project and i want to have have 6 mutually exclusive charuco boards, Opencv by default supports 4X4, 5X5, 6X6 , 7X7 and original dictionary. I want one more dictionary to create charuco board. Any Leads if opencv supports creation of a dictionary and its detection whose pattern doesn't match any of the predefined dictioanries.

Comment: am I guessing correctly that OpenCV's charuco boards require specific IDs for the markers in a board? because if it doesn't, you could stick to the lowest possible module density and just assign non-overlapping ID ranges. OpenCV's charuco could probably be extended to support this.

Comment: There is a getpredefineDictionary and a generateCustomDictionary function, but tbh. I dont have experience with those. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/df7/dictionary_8hpp.html